# Was found to be or found to be?

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Which of the following is correct?

> Based on the laboratory experiments, the strength of the sample was found to be 30MPa.

or

> Based on the laboratory experiments, the strength of the sample found to be 30MPa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct, the second not.

However, a better word might be ***determined***

> ***[Determine:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/determine)*** ascertain or establish exactly, typically as a result of research or calculation.

<sub>OED</sub>

*... the strength of the sample was determined to be 30Mpa*

Answer (score 1):

Only the first sentence is correct. The second sentence may be rendered correct by using "the strength of the sample proved / showed / demonstrated / turned out to be 30MPa."